# Using @Profile in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have spring boot application (**1.1.5.RELEASE**) and enabling my profiles via the configuration protperty `spring.profiles.active=MyProfile`

The profile gets activated correctly which I can see by beans from that profile being created.

Then I have a `@Controller` used as follows:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/someUrl")
@Profile("MyProfile")
public class MyController {
...
}
```

This controller is not instantiated and URL used in the controller are not mapped. In the same package I have another controllers which are not limited by `@Profile` and these get instsantiated and mapped as expected.

So is using `@Profile` annotation on controller something which is not compatible with spring boot? Is there other approach I should be using?

**Edit:** It seems to be a bug after all as if I include `-Dspring.profiles.active=MyProfile` as JVM property the controller gets instantiated **:'(**

**Edit2:** So here comes the interesting part:

- If you define `spring.profiles.active` in `application.properties` which is loaded by default from classpath  thne it works
- when you rename the file to `test.properties` and include it via `@PropertySource("classpath:test.properties")` it stops working. Will raise a bug against it.

**Edit 3:** As promised: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1417

Thanks!

Comment: For me it worked just fine even with the properties file!

Comment: To avoid duplication of effort it would be courteous to mention that you have opened an issue for this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1417

Comment: Thanks, goog point. Added that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tracked this down to what I believe to be a bug in Spring. See [SPR-12111](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12111) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely annotate a controller with @Profile in Spring Boot, just as you are doing above. MyController gets instantiated if MyProfile is active. Are you sure that "MyProfile" is the active profile? Are you setting the spring.profiles property?

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html
The @Profile annotation may be used in any of the following ways:

as a type-level annotation on any class directly or indirectly annotated with @Component, including @Configuration classes
as a meta-annotation, for the purpose of composing custom stereotype annotations

Comment: Where are you setting the `spring.profiles.active` ?

Comment: @JanZyka, I was setting it in application.properties, hadn't tried it with a different name. Interesting

Comment: Please if you have a spare minute could you just rename `application.properties` and use `@PropertySource("newName.properties")` on you top level `@Configuration` file?

Comment: @JanZyka, I did what you suggested and it broke just as you described. I even replaced the application.properties file and added a spring.config.name=myotherproperties. The other properties file sets the server port, so I knew it was being picked up. But as soon as I move spring.profiles and spring.profiles.active into the other properties file, it quits working.