# Provide Developer and Production URL Mail links in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot

**Example**

*in Development Mode and Production Mode the following link is same*

> If you requested this password change, please click the link below to set a new password:
>   http://www.facebook.com/reset_password?token=12345&email=test@gmail.com

**But i want two different links for Prod & Dev Such as**

*For Dev*

> If you requested this password change, please click the link below to set a new password:
>   http://www.facebook.com/reset_password?token=12345&email=test@gmail.com

*For Prod*

> If you requested this password change, please click the link below to set a new password:
>   http://www.twitter.com/reset_password?token=12345&email=test@gmail.com

Comment: Maybe [profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) can help you here

Answer (score 0):

You can have application.properties application-default.properties application-dev.properties etc

you can switch profiles by command line args to the jvm

you can override some things at test time using `@TestPropertySource`

Refer these links :

[How to override application.properties during production in Spring-Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23563363/how-to-override-application-properties-during-production-in-spring-boot)

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Comment: I Already Have 2 properties files, Thing is how to Change the Domain Name in URL While Sending Mails From DEV & PROD.

Comment: @LiyakhatAli Make use of a placeholder and replace the domain name using a property from application-{profile}.properties file.

Comment: @AkhilBojedla Do you have any example or Ref, that would be very much helpful