# Spring boot conditional jpa property

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have this in my `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=dbo
```

However, I sometimes need to disable this, since I have the same entities in two different database servers. One of them requires the schema to be present, the other one requires the schema to not be present.

Is there a way to programmatically disable or override some of the properties in `application.properties`? I'd like to keep the other properties, i.e. I'd not want to specify *everything* programmatically, just this one.

Comment: can you pass this while invoking? Like while calling `java -jar --spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=dbo`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23563363/how-to-override-application-properties-during-production-in-spring-boot

Comment: I don't think it would be a good idea to change the setting in the code on the fly. Possibly you have to configure multiple database connections or pass a command line flag or use different profiles. Maybe you can elaborate a bit more.

Comment: You can override spring properties on serveral levels. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config

Comment: @aksappy That's a potential solution, but doesn't allow for validation. E.g. you could still supply the schema when you should not (and programmatic validation would get rid of that issue).

Comment: @ced-b Added a clarification. Let me know if I should provide more info.

Comment: You should use `multi-tenancy` so that you can switch datasources based on what you want to do dynamically.

Comment: @Oneguy Can you clarify how switching data sources can drive the default hibernate schema?

Comment: @levantpied need to create a couple of classes for supporting multi-tenancy and one of them should implement CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver so that you can five the schema to change.