# Is it possible to dynamically generate Spring Boot application properties?

Tags: java, spring-boot, frameworks

Is it possible to dynamically generate Spring Boot application properties based on external configuration files or a database at runtime, without requiring a restart of the application?

insights into the feasibility of achieving this requirement and suggest possible approaches or techniques that can be used to implement such functionality.

Comment: this is way too vague. Everything is possible but no one will be able to help you until your formulate what exactly do you want to be loaded dynamically depending on which exact factor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override application.properties during production in Spring-Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23563363/how-to-override-application-properties-during-production-in-spring-boot)

Comment: Did you try to create a config server? 
example: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-configuration
Also you could use `@RefreshScope`